# Check string array elements only contain elements in another array

Tags: c#, linq

I have 2 arrays

```
string[] allPossible = {"ID","Age","FirstName","LastName","Gender","Kudos"};
string[] enteredItems = {"Age", "LastName"};
```

I want to check the array enteredItems only contains elements found in the array
allPossible.  I want to do this with LINQ.

I have looked

```
allPossible.Any(el => enteredItems .Contains(el));
```

and

```
allPossible.Intersect(enteredItems).Any();
```

Instead I loop thru the enteredItems and use `Array.IndexOf(allPossible, x) == -1 return false`.

The top data sample would return would return true...
however if only 1 element in the enteredItems array is not in the allPossible array then 
there will be a false.  ie.

```
string[] allPossible = {"ID","Age","FirstName","LastName","Gender","Kudos"};
string[] enteredItems = {"Age", "Geeky"};
```

would be false because 1 element in the 'enteredItems' array does not exist in the 'allPossible'
element.

There must be a LINQ query to do this.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use [`Enumerable.Except`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb300779.aspx)

```
bool allInEntered = !enteredItems.Except(allPossible).Any();
```

Comment: Wow, that's a sweet one liner.